# Trouble with regular expression when using 2 patterns

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a method I call during `UITextView` updates that helps me detect hashtags and username mentions eg. `#hashtag` and `@username`

This code works perfectly if I only try to detect one at a time. I can either detect hashtags only, or username mentions only.

I am trying to make it so that it will detect both.

Here are my two regex patterns:

1. Hashtag: `#(\\w+)`
2. Username: `@(\\w+)`

Here is my detection method:

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString*)decorateTags:(NSString *)stringWithTags{

NSError *error = nil;

// Hashtag detection
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+) | @(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:stringWithTags options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, stringWithTags.length)];
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringWithTags];

NSInteger stringLength = [stringWithTags length];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {

    NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];

    NSString* word = [stringWithTags substringWithRange:wordRange];

    // Set Foreground Color
    UIColor *foregroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:foregroundColor range:wordRange];

    NSLog(@"Found tag %@", word);

  }
   return attString;
}
```

The above code works perfectly, but like I said it is only currently setup to detect one at a time. So I modified the regex pattern to search for both hashtags and username mentions, and I tried using several operators like `|, +, *, *+, ++, +,` etc. and none of them allow for detecting both hashtags and usernames, and just to be clear here's what I mean by both:

> "Hey **@John** check out this **#hashtag**"

See how both are highlighted? That's what I need, but after testing with the operators provided in the apple regex docs I can only either get one to highlight or none at all.

For example with the above sample code, #hashtag will highlight but @John will not.

Here are some quick examples of how I tried to use the operators:

```
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+) + @(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];

[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+) | @(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];

[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+) * @(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: "(<[^>]*?>)|<style(.*?)style>" this two patterns using or operator fails though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're using only matches the first one. If you set a breakpoint before you start iterating you'll see that the count of matches is 1.

The reason the second thing isn't being matched is because the whitespace surrounding the `|` is being counted.

Using a regex like `(#|@)(\\w+)` works for this case. I set up a sample project to test this regex and it works.

[image]

Comment: this pattern break when special character In.

Comment: You could use (\\S+) instead of (\\w+) if you want to capture special characters

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that my code with the `| (OR)` operator was just fine. The problem was that there was an extra space on each side of the operator.

Here's the working regex:

```
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)|@(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];
```